# Check that user selected the same tab in UITabBarController

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

I have a subclass of `UITabBarController`. The question is: is there a way to check if user selected the already selected `UITabBarItem`?

I have tried 
`didSet` for `selectedIndex` and `selectedViewController` as well as different delegate methods:

`func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, shouldSelect viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool`

`func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, didSelect viewController: UIViewController)`

`func tabBar(_ tabBar: UITabBar, didSelect item: UITabBarItem)`

But they all are called only if it's a different tab (and `selectedIndex` is not called at all)

I need that, for example, if I want to scroll the currently opened controller to the top and if it is not the currently opened controller then I don't want to scroll it, I just want to show it (and also some other stuff related to animations).

Thanks

**EDIT**
There is another issue with my code which prevents method
`override func tabBar(_ tabBar: UITabBar, didSelect item: UITabBarItem)`
 from being called. As in a clear "fresh" project it works like expected. Thanks

Comment: NO. tabBar(_ tabBar: UITabBar, didSelect item: UITabBarItem) will gets called even if you select the same tab item.

Comment: selectedIndex has the index of already selected tab. You can use this to check if you are selecting the same tab again or not.

Comment: @TejaNandamuri it seems that I have some other issue in my code which prevents `tabBar(_ tabBar: UITabBar, didSelect item: UITabBarItem)` from being called as I have checked it with a clear project and it works. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a quick method that could help you.

```
override func tabBar(_ tabBar: UITabBar, didSelect item: UITabBarItem) {
    let currentIndex = tabBar.items?.firstIndex(of: item)
    if selectedIndex == 0 && currentIndex == 0 {
        // Do Something
    } else if selectedIndex == 1 && currentIndex == 1 {
        // Do Something
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. It seems that I have some other issue in my code which prevents `tabBar(_ tabBar: UITabBar, didSelect item: UITabBarItem)` from being called as I have checked it with a clear project and it works.

Comment: Mmm only thing I can think of is that maybe you are not setting the delegate. Make sure your class conforms to UITabBarControllerDelegate. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks :) The problem was that I had 2 invisible views in front of my `UITabBar` which we're used for some animations. And one of them had `isUserInteractionEnabled = false` and the other, the one right on top of the current active tab, did not